# DDL FOR SUPERTYPE AND SUBTYPE ORACLE

Tags: oracle, ddl, erd, subtype, supertype

I have an entity with supertype: tb_transaksi with attributes: id_transaksi (pk), tgl_transaksi
and 2 subtypes, namely:
debit_card with attribute: no_kartu
and credit_card with attribute: persen_bunga.

But when I generate into DDL form an error occurs like this:

```
ERROR: No Discriminator Column found in Arc FKArc_1 - constraint trigger for Arc cannot be generated
ERROR: No Discriminator Column found in Arc FKArc_1 - constraint trigger for Arc cannot be generated
```

what do I have to do?

DDL STATEMENT :

> CREATE TABLE cash (
> id_transaksi   NUMBER(10, 2) NOT NULL,
> nominal        NUMBER(10, 2) NOT NULL );
>
> ALTER TABLE cash ADD CONSTRAINT cash_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_transaksi );
>
> CREATE TABLE credit (
> id_transaksi   NUMBER(10, 2) NOT NULL,
> nomor_kartu    NUMBER(10, 2) NOT NULL );
>
> ALTER TABLE credit ADD CONSTRAINT credit_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_transaksi
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE tb_transaksi (
> id_transaksi NUMBER(10, 2) NOT NULL );
>
> ALTER TABLE tb_transaksi ADD CONSTRAINT tb_transaksi_pk PRIMARY KEY (
> id_transaksi );
>
> ALTER TABLE cash
> ADD CONSTRAINT cash_tb_transaksi_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_transaksi )
> REFERENCES tb_transaksi ( id_transaksi );
>
> ALTER TABLE credit
> ADD CONSTRAINT credit_tb_transaksi_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_transaksi )
> REFERENCES tb_transaksi ( id_transaksi );
>
> --  ERROR: No Discriminator Column found in Arc FKArc_1 - constraint trigger for Arc cannot be generated
>
> --  ERROR: No Discriminator Column found in Arc FKArc_1 - constraint trigger for Arc cannot be generated

Comment: add all the ddl statements you are using and a reproducible example

Comment: I have added the ddl statements.

Comment: the error has nothing to do with Oracle.